# What exactly is affected by "Default download method" setting?

Tags: files

At `/admin/config/media/file-system` is option **Default download method** (public or private files) which sets "the preferred download method".

I am not sure what exactly is affected by this setting? Apparently I can create a type of content with two fields for files: one field for files stored as public files, another field for files stored as private files. So I can use both public and private files simultaneously.

Let me stress my question **is not** about the difference between public and private files – I understand it. I just wonder about meaning of the above mentioned setting.

Comment: My personal thoughts are that it's a leftover legacy from earlier versions of Drupal. It was there in D6, and I can't remember if it was in D5. At the time, there was only one setting for downloads, and it was site-wide. This is probably still what this setting does - sets the default setting for file storage site wide. However, pretty much anywhere with file configuration allows for the setting to be set at that level. This is just my speculation though.

Comment: It's used by core and modules when they need to store files. E.g. the image module will store its "styles" folder in either public or private depending on what this is set to

Comment: Thanks for reaction. Concerning images: it seems that image field can be set to use public or private files. So I hope it generally does not matter too much which download method is set at `/admin/config/media/file-system`.

Comment: Clarification: I misunderstood the difference between types of fields _Image_  (which can choose file system) and _Entity reference_ (which **cannot** choose file system). Anyway, I can still have public and private images if I need, so everything seems ok. :-)